# cover return statement in test class?

Tags: unit-test, try-catch

can someone help with test class covering in a try catch block? the first methods maybe is not necessary but anyway, is the same issue with all methods. help pls! (65% covered)

**Class Controller**

```
public with sharing class CreateProjectController {
    
    public static List<Opportunity> OpportunityList(String idOpportunity){
        try{
            List<Opportunity> opp = [SELECT Name, JiraProjectKey__c, OpportunityTemplate__r.Name, Project__r.Id, Account.Name, Account.ProjectKey__c 
                                     FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: idOpportunity LIMIT 1];
            System.debug('OpportunityList : ' +opp);
            return opp;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('Error  en OpportunityList' +e);
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    public static List<Quote> QuoteList(String idOpportunity){
        try{
            List<Quote> quote = [SELECT Id, Name, Clarification__c FROM Quote WHERE OpportunityId =: idOpportunity AND IsSyncing=true LIMIT 1]; //Campo Sprints en Quote?
            System.debug('QuoteList: ' + quote);
            return quote;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('Error en QuoteList' + e);
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    public static String Scope(String idOpportunity){
        try{
            List<Quote> quote = QuoteList(idOpportunity);
            String clarification = quote[0].Clarification__c;
            
            String quitarP = clarification.replace('<p>', '');
            String finalClarification = quitarP.replace('</p>', '');
            
            System.debug('Scope : ' + finalClarification);
            return finalClarification;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.debug('Error en Scope :' + ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static String Key(String idOpportunity){
        try{
            List<Opportunity> opp = OpportunityList(idOpportunity);
            String IdProject = opp[0].Project__r.Id;
            
            String nameAccount = opp[0].Account.Name;
            String finalkeyAccount = nameAccount.substring(0, 5);
            String keyOpportunity = opp[0].JiraProjectKey__c;
           
            String key = finalkeyAccount.toUpperCase() + keyOpportunity.toUpperCase();
            System.debug('Key :' + key);
            return key;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.debug('Error en key' + ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    public static String Name(String idOpportunity){
        try{
            List<Opportunity> opp = OpportunityList(idOpportunity);
            String IdProject = opp[0].Project__r.Id;
            
            String NameAccount = opp[0].Account.Name;
            String keyOpportunity = opp[0].OpportunityTemplate__r.Name;
           
            String name = NameAccount.toLowerCase() + keyOpportunity.toLowerCase();
            System.debug('Nombre : ' + name);
            return name;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.debug('Error al crear el nombre del proyecto' + ex);
            return null;
        }
        
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String CreateProject(String idOpportunity){
        
        String statusProjecto = null;
        
        String name = Name(idOpportunity);
        String scope = Scope(idOpportunity);
        String key = Key(idOpportunity);
        
        Project__c project = new Project__c(); 
        project.Name = name;
        project.Scope__c = scope;
        project.Key__c = key;
        insert project;
            
        String IdProjectCreated = project.Id;
        try{
            Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id, Name, Project__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: idOpportunity LIMIT 1];
            if(project.Name != null && project.Key__c!= null && project.Scope__c != null ){
                if(opp.Project__c == null){
                    opp.Project__c = IdProjectCreated;
                    update opp;
                    
                    statusProjecto = '1';
                    System.debug('Proyecto Creado');
                }                
                else{
                    statusProjecto = '2';
                    System.debug('El proyecto ya existe en la oportunidad');
                }
            }
            System.debug(statusProjecto);
            return statusProjecto;             
        }catch(Exception e){
            statusProjecto = '0';         
            System.debug('No se creó el proyecto, faltan campos' +e);
            return statusProjecto;
        }   
    }
    
}
```

**Test class**

```
@isTest
public class CreateProjectControllerTest {
    @isTest
    static void testController(){
         Product2 product = new Product2(
            Name = 'Example Product',
            Description = 'This is the Product description.',
            ProductCode = 'EX1234',
            StockKeepingUnit = 'EX5678',
            Family = 'Example Product Family',
            QuantityUnitOfMeasure = 'inches',
            DisplayUrl = 'https://www.example.com/',
            ExternalId = 'ID #1234',
            IsActive = true);
        insert product;

        // Insert the Product in the Standard Price Book (if necessary)
        PricebookEntry standardPriceBookEntry = new PricebookEntry(
            Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(),
            Product2Id = product.Id,
            UnitPrice = 100.00,
            UseStandardPrice = false,
            IsActive = true);
        insert standardPriceBookEntry;
        
        // Create a Pricebook
        Pricebook2 priceBook = new Pricebook2(
            Name = 'Small Business Price Book',
            Description = 'This is the Price Book description.',
            IsActive = true);
        insert priceBook;

        // Insert the Product in the New Price Book
        PricebookEntry priceBookEntry = new PricebookEntry(
            Pricebook2Id = priceBook.Id,
            Product2Id = product.Id,
            UnitPrice = 100.00,
            UseStandardPrice = false,
            IsActive = true
        );
        insert priceBookEntry;
        
        Account account = new Account(
            Name='Test Account',
            //Price_Book__c=priceBook.Id,
            NumberOfEmployees=20,
            Type='Customer',
            BillingStreet='av univ', 
            BillingCity='bj', 
            //BillingState='cdmx', 
            BillingCountry='Argentina', 
            BillingPostalCode='1704');
        insert account;
        
        Project__c project = new Project__c(
            Name = 'name',
            Scope__c = 'scope',
            Key__c = 'KEY');
        insert project;
        
        Opportunity oppTemplate = new Opportunity(
            Name='Opportunity Template',
            StageName='Discovery',
            CloseDate=System.today().addMonths(1),
            AccountId=account.Id,
            Pricebook2Id=priceBook.Id,
            Product_Families__c='Salesforce Marketing Cloud',
            RecordTypeId=Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Opportunity_Template').getRecordTypeId());
        insert oppTemplate;

        OpportunityLineItem cloneOpportunityLineItem = new OpportunityLineItem(
            OpportunityID=oppTemplate.Id,
            Quantity= 1,
            UnitPrice=1,
            Description='Prueba',
            Product2Id=product.Id,
            PricebookEntryId=pricebookEntry.Id);
        insert cloneOpportunityLineItem;  

        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity (
            Name='Opportunity',
            StageName='Discovery',
            CloseDate=System.today().addMonths(1),
            AccountId=account.Id,
            Pricebook2Id=priceBook.Id,
            Product_Families__c='Salesforce Marketing Cloud',
            JiraProjectKey__c = 'ASDF',
            Project__c = project.Id);
        insert opp;
        
        Quote quotes = new Quote (
            Name = 'Quote Test',
            OpportunityId = opp.id , 
            Clarification__c='clarification', 
            Pricebook2Id = priceBook.Id,
            Footer__c='Footer'); 
        insert quotes;
        
        //set quote to isyncing by linking it to the opportunity
        opp.SyncedQuoteId = quotes.Id;
        update opp;
   
        
        Test.startTest();
            CreateProjectController.CreateProject('');
        Test.stopTest();
        //AQUI
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't have any try-catch blocks.  Please [edit] your post to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: I have rolled back the question so that it shows the code to which sfdcfox responded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need **any** of the catch blocks here. Let's take a look at your queries:

```
public static List<Opportunity> OpportunityList(String idOpportunity){
  return [SELECT Name, JiraProjectKey__c, OpportunityTemplate__r.Name, Project__r.Id, Account.Name, Account.ProjectKey__c 
                                 FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: idOpportunity LIMIT 1];
}
```

This is all you need, considering no possible catchable exception can happen here.

For other methods, you just need to make sure the list contains at least one record:

```
public static String Scope(String idOpportunity){
    List<Quote> quote = QuoteList(idOpportunity);
    String result;
    if(quote.size() > 0) {
        result = quote[0].Clarification__c?.replace('<p>', '').replace('</p>', '');
    }
    return result;
}
```

So, get rid of all the try-catch blocks. Optimize your code, your unit test should be fine.